# Share and mutate object between different TypeScript classes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reference, es6-class

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
class ClassA {
    options: ClassOption;
    B: ClassB;

    constructor() {
        this.B = new ClassB(this.options);
        this.changeOptions();
    }

    changeOptions(): void {
        const newOptions: ClassOption = new ClassOption("something");
        this.options = newOptions;
    } 
}

class ClassB {
    options: ClassOption;

    constructor(opts: ClassOptions) {
        this.options = opts;
    }

    someFunction(): ClassOption {
        return this.options;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I instantiate `ClassA`:

```
const a = new ClassA();
```

`a.B.someFunction();` returns `undefined` instead of the new options that are set from `ClassA`'s `changeOptions` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in `ClassA`'s constructor yo do:

```
this.B = new ClassB(this.options);
```

`this.options` is still `undefined`, so basically when in `ClassB`'s constructor your do:

```
this.options = opt;
```

You are just setting `this.options` to `undefined` instead of assigning it a reference to `ClassA`'s `options`, which doesn't exist as it hasn't been initialised.

Even if you initialise `options` in `ClassA` with an empty object, if you assign (`this.options = something`) a new value to it, `ClassB` won't be referencing the new value.

What you want to do instead is:

1. Initialize `ClassA`'s `this.options` with an empty object:

   ```
   options: ClassOption = {};
   ```
2. Pass that to `ClassB`'s constructor. No changes needed here.
3. When calling `ChangeOptions`, **mutate that same object instead of replacing it with a new one**. You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge both objects:

   ```
   changeOptions(): void {
       const newOptions: ClassOption = new ClassOption("something");
       Object.assign(this.options, newOptions);
       // Note that after this, `this.options`' reference is preserved.
   }
   ```

Here you can see it working in plain JavaScript:

```js
class ClassA {
   constructor() {
      // 1. Initialise with an empty object:
      this.options = {};
      
      // 2. Pass that reference to ClassB instead of undefined:
      this.B = new ClassB(this.options);
      
      this.changeOptions();
   }
   
   changeOptions() {
      // 3. Mutate this.options without changing its reference:
      Object.assign(this.options, {
        opt1: 1,  
        opt2: 2, 
      });
      
      // 3. You can also do it like this:
      this.options.opt3 = 3;
   } 
}

class ClassB {
   constructor(options) {
      this.options = options;
   }
   
   getOptions() {
      return this.options;
   }
}
 
const a = new ClassA();

a.changeOptions();

console.log(a.B.getOptions());
```

Comment: In my case, those `options` references are replaced by the various functions in `ClassA`. And I expected the changed value to be reflected in `ClassB` when any of the functions using `options` in `ClassB` is called i. I will try mutating the object that is initially created and see if it resolved the issue and will respond back here.

Comment: Cannot assign empty object: `{}` to typed `this.options` property, which is of the type `ClassOption`

Comment: Mutating the object using `Object.assign` worked instead of replacing with a new object. Although I was unable to set `this.options` to `{}` in typescript, I was able to create a new object using the `new` operator.